# Rearranging Proportional Controller

Tags: transfer-function

I have a transfer function for G(s) and need to rearrange for G1(s).

[image]

After a LOT of playing around I have worked out that the correct answer is as shown in the image.

My problem is that I need to know the steps required to rearrange from the first form to the second. I can get most of the way but think I am missing a rule of rearraging equasions allowing me to complete this task. I have only managed to complete it through trial and error. I have even tried rearranging backwards, to no avail!

Is someone able to provide a step through of how to do this?
I will be eternally grateful! :)

Comment: If you show your work, it could be helpful, someone could more easily spot your mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few comments first:

- It turns out that you have a correct equivalence, as there is no error in your final equation if you assume the first equation is also correct. How you achieved that, without having *any* of the basic algebraic skills needed and by *only "playing around"*, is a mystery to me. My guess is that somehow you were already able to find the right answer but not through just play.
- You haven't shown any of the steps you tried taking. Perhaps that is because of the work you imagine in creating images for each step you tried. But you can use Latex, just fine. If that was your only problem and if you plan on posting here again, I'd recommend learning some Latex and the use of a paired set of \\$ and/or $\$\$$ to inform the web site here that you are writing Latex math.
- The fact that you aren't able to proceed from your first equation, then solving for \$G_1\left(s\right)\$, tells me a great deal about your need for a great deal of algebra practice. This kind of work is perhaps a struggle for children just learning algebra. But not someone engaging in transfer functions.

Since you couldn't solve it, I'll assume you need me to take incremental, remedial steps. Follow here:

$$\begin{align*}
G\left(s\right)&=\frac{k\cdot G_1\left(s\right)}{1+k\cdot G_1\left(s\right)}\\ \\
G\left(s\right)\cdot \left[1+k\cdot G_1\left(s\right)\right]&=k\cdot G_1\left(s\right) \\ \\
G\left(s\right)+G\left(s\right)\cdot k\cdot G_1\left(s\right)&=k\cdot G_1\left(s\right) \\ \\
G\left(s\right)&=k\cdot G_1\left(s\right) - G\left(s\right)\cdot k\cdot G_1\left(s\right) \\ \\
G\left(s\right)&=k\cdot G_1\left(s\right)\cdot\left[1 - G\left(s\right)\right] \\ \\
\frac{G\left(s\right)}{1 - G\left(s\right)}&=k\cdot G_1\left(s\right) \\ \\
G_1\left(s\right) &=\frac{1}{k}\cdot\frac{G\left(s\right)}{1 - G\left(s\right)} \\ \\
G_1\left(s\right) &=\frac{1}{k}\cdot\left[\frac{G\left(s\right)}{1 - G\left(s\right)}+1-1\right] \\ \\
G_1\left(s\right) &=\frac{1}{k}\cdot\left[\frac{G\left(s\right)}{1 - G\left(s\right)}+\frac{1 - G\left(s\right)}{1 - G\left(s\right)}-1\right] \\ \\
G_1\left(s\right) &=\frac{1}{k}\cdot\left[\frac{G\left(s\right)+1 - G\left(s\right)}{1 - G\left(s\right)}-1\right] \\ \\
G_1\left(s\right) &=\frac{1}{k}\cdot\left[\frac{1}{1 - G\left(s\right)}-1\right] \\ \\
G_1\left(s\right) &=\frac{\frac{1}{1 - G\left(s\right)}-1}{k}
\end{align*}$$

That's really all there is to the process. It's just algebraic manipulation to solve for a term. A very basic algebraic skill you need to acquire.

Comment: I had been tasked to rearrange for G1(s) only, no answer supplied.

As explained previously I had worked out most of the steps, but got stuck halfway. I overcame it by assigning simple values to the parts of the equasion & with a calculator & a lot of trial and error found a solution.

I can see now that you have posted a far simpler solution for G1(s).

I am 31 years old, on a control theory course, and indeed struggling to quickly pick up maths skills lost a long time ago!
Thankyou for replying, this has been very helpful, although it is a shame it had to come with so much spite.

Comment: @Johnnohj I didn't mean any spite, at all. I'm just pushing you. You didn't show _any_ of your steps. Pointing that fact out is appropriate. And you really do need to work hard on your algebra. Pointing that out is my attempt to get you to drill down and work hard on it. Without those basic skills, the rest will be near to hopeless. I honestly _do_ want to help and that is the reason I took the time to write out each modest step. (Had it been a matter of spite, I wouldn't have written an answer at all. Just quipped.) I'm glad it helped. Seriously glad about that. You do have my best wishes.

Comment: Thanks Jonk, understood. Im drilling down pretty hard atm, just wish there was more time in a day!

Comment: @Johnnohj I get it. Just keep pressing on algebraic manipulation skills as you can afford to. And if you can, find someone to help. They can listen to how you are currently thinking about things and help pass along how they think about things, too. An insight or two will help you a lot. And books just don't entirely cut it, here. Being able to interact with someone who listens and offers their own ideas can help smooth the road a lot.